# Getting error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am following a course from Wesbos on Node.js, and I created a `/add` GET route that uses the `addStore` controller:

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const storeController = require('../controllers/storeController')
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers')

router.get('/',                catchErrors(storeController.getStores))

router.get('/stores',          catchErrors(storeController.getStores))

router.get('/add',             catchErrors(storeController.addStore))
router.post('/add',            catchErrors(storeController.createStore))
router.post('/add/:id',        catchErrors(storeController.updateStore))

router.get('/stores/:id/edit', catchErrors(storeController.editStore))

module.exports = router
```

storeController.js:

```
exports.addStore = (req, res) => {
  res.render('editStore', { title: 'add store'})
}
```

But when i go to the add route i get the error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Here is the editStore and storeform view:

editStore:

```
extends layout
include mixins/_storeForm

block content
  .inner
    h2= title
    +storeForm(store)
```

storeForm:

```
mixin storeForm(store = {})
  form(action=`/add/${store._id || ''}` method="POST" class="card")
    label(for="name") Name
    input(type="text" name="name" value=store.name)
    label(for="description") Description
    textarea(name="description")= store.description
    - const choices = ['wifi','Open-late','Family Friendly', 'vegetarian','licensced']
    - const tags = store.tags || []
    ul.tags
      each choice in choices
        .tag.tag__choice
          input(type="checkbox" id=choice value=choice name="tags" checked=(tags.includes(choice)))
          label(for=choice) #{choice}
    input(type="submit" value="Save" class="button")
```

catchErrors:

```
/*
  Catch Errors Handler
  With async/await, you need some way to catch errors
  Instead of using try{} catch(e) {} in each controller, we wrap the function in
  catchErrors(), catch any errors they throw, and pass it along to our express middleware with next()
*/

exports.catchErrors = (fn) => {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    return fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};

/*
  Not Found Error Handler
  If we hit a route that is not found, we mark it as 404 and pass it along to the next error handler to display
*/
exports.notFound = (req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
};

/*
  MongoDB Validation Error Handler
  Detect if there are mongodb validation errors that we can nicely show via flash messages
*/

exports.flashValidationErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  if (!err.errors) return next(err);
  // validation errors look like
  const errorKeys = Object.keys(err.errors);
  errorKeys.forEach(key => req.flash('error', err.errors[key].message));
  res.redirect('back');
};


/*
  Development Error Handler
  In development we show good error messages so if we hit a syntax error or any other previously un-handled error, we can show good info on what happened
*/
exports.developmentErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.stack = err.stack || '';
  const errorDetails = {
    message: err.message,
    status: err.status,
    stackHighlighted: err.stack.replace(/[a-z_-\d]+.js:\d+:\d+/gi, '<mark>$&</mark>')
  };
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.format({
    // Based on the `Accept` http header
    'text/html': () => {
      res.render('error', errorDetails);
    }, // Form Submit, Reload the page
    'application/json': () => res.json(errorDetails) // Ajax call, send JSON back
  });
};


/*
  Production Error Handler
  No stacktraces are leaked to user
*/
exports.productionErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
};
```

Link to my repo: https://github.com/GiorgioMartini/learnnode/tree/master/maketogether

Comment: Just a quick thought, I would try adding `return` in-front `res.render('editStore', { title: 'add store'})` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: What is `catchErrors()`?

Comment: catchErrors goes through several errors that might happen: https://github.com/GiorgioMartini/learnnode/blob/master/maketogether/handlers/errorHandlers.js

Comment: Please post complete code from index.js

Comment: I have updated index...thx

Comment: Please post you catchErrors function

Comment: @RajikaImal I have updated the post with the catchErrors, thx! :)

Comment: Updated the post @SanSolo thx! :)